# How to get a string from a regex match in vb.net?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have :

```
Dim Text = "some text here ###MONTH-3### some text here ###MONTH-2### some text here"
Dim regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("###MONTH[+-][0-9]###")
For Each match In regex.Matches(Text)
    // What to write here ?
    // So, that ###MONTH-i### gets replaced with getmonth(i)
    // Therefore, final Text will be :
    // Text = "some text here" + getmonth(-3) + "some text here" + getmonth(-2) + "some text here"
Next match
```

I think I have explained my problem properly..

**So, can you please help ?**

Comment: yeah, you REALLY should start using Option Explicit ...

Comment: He could be using [Option Infer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384665.aspx).  No sense writing code the compiler can figure out for you.

Comment: True, I guess that's acceptable for literals and very obvious expressions.

Comment: Why did you adviced to use `Option Explicit` ?
> How can that be helpful here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you want, I think.

```
Dim text As String = "some text here ###MONTH-3### some text here ###MONTH-2### ..."
Dim regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("###MONTH[+-][0-9]###")

return regex.replace(text, AddressOf GetMonthFromMatch)

Function GetMonthFromMatch(ByVal m As Match) As String
    ' Get the matched string.
    Dim matchText As String = m.ToString()

    Dim offset As Int = Integer.Parse(matchText.Right(2))
    Return getmonth(offset)
End Function
```

This uses the `GetMonthFromMatch` delegate to process each match and in turn call the `getmonth` function. The `RegEx.Replace` function will use the delegate to substitute each match.

Answer (score 1):

First slightly modify your regex:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("###MONTH([+-][0-9])###")
```

As you can see, I've just put number and +/- in parentheses. This is so that we can retrieve them later.

So now you can access just data you need (e.g. -3) whit this line of code:

```
match.Groups(1).Value
```

EDIT:

There's even an easier way :) Just use Replace function.

In your example it would go like this:

```
Dim regex = New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("###MONTH([+-][0-9])###")
regex.Replace(Text, "getmonth($1)")
```

$1 references to first parentheses in the regular expression, so instead of $1 there will be what ever month it actually is.

Comment: This would simply insert the literal text "getmonth(-3)" to the input string. He wants to run a `getmonth` function and insert the *result*.

Comment: Ya.. Justin is right.. I want to run the function `getmonth(-3)` and replace the value.